# How to create segue from Detail disclosure of static cell from xib file

Tags: swift, segue

Have some question that I can't figure out. I have single static cell in xib file and I want to make segue from detail disclosure accessory of that cell to other view controller.

Guess that I have to use this method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueID", sender: self) // #ERROR
}
```

But I have an error:

> Could not cast value of type 'Lists.ListViewController'
>   (0x104c0e7b8) to 'UITableViewCell' (0x106875bf8).

How can I create this segue correctly?

Comment: Why you want sender as **disclosure button class**?

Comment: @NiravD that was just example. I've just edited question.

Comment: Where you are getting these error?

Comment: @NiravD in the line self.performSegue..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to access the cell in `prepareForSegue` you can try like this way.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Pass the indexPath as sender
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueID", sender: indexPath)
}
```

Now access that indexPath in `prepareForSegue`.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SegueID" {
        let nextVC =  segue.destination as! DestinationVC
        if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath,
           let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath) as? CustomCell {
              //access your cell here
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Never know that sender could be indexPath... Thank you!

Comment: @wm.p1us Welcome mate :)